# Mailchimp RSS feed work with single wordpress page?

Tags: pages, rss

I'm trying to implement automated emails which sends my subscribers an email when a single page on my website is updated. The single page contains a table with data which updated manually every day.

Will Mailchimp recognise when a single page is updated or does it only work when a new post is published?

Forgive me as this question isn't directly related to coding but I didn't know where else to ask.

Comment: You would need to ask the developer of the plugin.

Comment: I'm using a plugin to display the table contents but this is done through a shortcode so the actual content is outputted in the RSS feed in the description tag. I'm asking if the updated date will be recognised by Mailchimp?

Comment: So you're not using a Mailchimp plugin? Just sending the RSS feed to Mailchimp? You'd need to ask them. They're the ones who'd decide when/whether a change to the feed will do anything.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. My first thought was to contact them but they don't offer any means of contacting them if you're not a pro customer. Their documentation also doesn't mention anything about this...